# Regular Expression that accepts special characters except ; and must contain one alpha numeric character

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is what I came up with but it also accepts `;` . Can someone help me understand what I am missing

```
var VALID_ALPHANUMERIC_WITH_SPECIAL_CHARS = /^(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]|[@#!%*&_\/.:{}\[\]\$\-\=\?\\\(\)\+\~\`\^\<\>])+$/;
```

Thanks

Comment: Try wrapping everything except `^$` in parentheses. I guess you have an alternation at the top level.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that there are at least one alphanumeric character, and allows alphanumeric + some special characters in the text, then the regex below should work. I also take my liberty to remove some unnecessary escaping.

```
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9@#!%*&_\/.:{}\[\]$=?\\()+~`^<>-]+$/
```

It can be further simplify in some places, but I leave them alone for clarity.

Comment: Why the heck downvote? And without a single explanation also!

Comment: I only can upvote this once, unfortunately. I would really like to hear the reason for the downvotes.

Comment: Maybe the downvoter was thinking the `.*` in the lookahead allows `;`, but that's not a problem because the main part does *not* match `;`.  You're also assuming the *one* in "one alphanumeric character" means **at least** one, but that's how I read it, too.  This is the best answer, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

@nhahtdh has already provided a correct regex for you. If you want to understand why your regex failed, let's take a look at it:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])   # Either anchor the match at the start and assert
               # that there is at least one ASCII digit
|              # OR
               # Assert that there is
(?=.*[a-zA-Z]) # at least one ASCII letter, then match
([a-zA-Z0-9]|[special chars...])+ # one or more of these characters
$              # with an unnecessary alternation; anchor the match to the end
```

Do you see the problems?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept special characters except `;` with *exactly one* alpha numeric character

```
var re = /^[@#!%*&_\/.:{}\[\]$\-=?\\()+~`^<>]*[a-zA-Z0-9][@#!%*&_\/.:{}\[\]$\-=?\\()+~`^<>]*$/;
```

If you want special characters except `;` with *at least one* alpha numeric character

```
var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9@#!%*&_\/.:{}\[\]$\-=?\\()+~`^<>]*[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9@#!%*&_\/.:{}\[\]$\-=?\\()+~`^<>]*$/;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HZbTb/) for testing.

Answer (score 0):

This part `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` matches any character followed by a letter, so it matches `;a`

You can do `(?=[^;]*[a-zA-Z])` in order to match any character but `;`